# Displaying minimised windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, window-manager

When I minimize safari, finder or Firefox windows, they move down to the dock. When I use Command + Tab , to move back to them, the minimized windows don't appear, just the top menu bar is changed. I have to click on the docked thumbnail to maximize particular window. Is it possible to maximize windows with only command + tab.

thanks

Comment: excellent question.  this behaviour is something I struggle with too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Use <kbd>Command-Tab</kbd> to tab to the app as usual
2. *Before* releasing the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, press <kbd>Option</kbd> as well
3. Release <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>
4. Release <kbd>Option</kbd>

Doing it is actually easier than explaining it, so just give it a try!

Comment: +1 great answer and great job for finding this. Edited with a minor correction - You don't hold down the tab key (obviously), only the command key after selecting the app you want.

Comment: thanks, just one thing more to say that, if suppose two firefox windows are minimized, when I perform shortcuts as said above, it only brings one of the window, not showing all at same time. Is it possible that can be done also :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the nicest way in the world, but Ctrl + F3 allows you to move along your Dock icons with the keyboard arrows, then Enter/Return will bring it back up.

Oh, just found a nicer way through, Tab through to the app you want, then hold Option on your keyboard and it'll bring the window back up. Not sure if that'll work for every app, but it worked in Skype & Safari. [Details on Lifehacker.](http://lifehacker.com/384167/open-new-windows-via-command+tab)