# Use Command + Tab to view a minimized application window

Tags: mojave, window-manager, keybindings

Maybe it's related to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/26595/124094), but when I use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through open applications, if a leave the selection on an application that is minimized, I can select it, but it doesn't display over the previous application window.

How can I force <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to bring the selected application to my current view?

Currently, I switch to that application window, then I have to go with the mouse to the dock to click and bring it back to the foreground.

---

*update*: Here's the screen recording: https://youtu.be/wv_hssds7yQ

Comment: Have you rebooted since this started?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, and I've edited my question with screen recording, right after a fresh restart.